# Why there is time difference in Django time and time stored in SQLITE3

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I have the following Django framework:

**models.py**

```
import django
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime
from django.utils import timezone

class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=django.utils.timezone.now,blank=True)
```

Now in the browser it looks like this:

[image]

But when in sqlite3 it looks like this:

```
sqlite> select * from test_app_question;
8|Who is it?|2015-10-21 07:28:08
```

Note the difference in time `07:28:08` versus `16:28:08`. Somehow the Django recognize the TIME_ZONE setting but not SQLITE3. How can I resolve the issue?

In my **settings.py** I have:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Japan'  
USE_I18N = True  
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
```

Answer (score 4):

From [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/timezones/) (very first line):

> When support for time zones is enabled, Django stores datetime information in UTC in the database, uses time-zone-aware datetime objects internally, and translates them to the end user’s time zone in templates and forms.

As there is 9 hours difference between UTC and Japan's time (Japan's time is UTC+9) so the difference in the values from DB and from template.